# IPTABLES and sudoers file issue

Tags: linux, iptables, sudo

I have a script file on a debian server machine that uses /sbin/iptables to ban ips that are trying to enter to my system. I had the script as a crontab entry but I've realised that it wasn't working as expected because it needed to be a root user.

Whenever I run the script as sudo myscript the the script works as expected. If I don't use sudo it gives me:

```
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded
```

If I type "id" I get:

```
uid=1000(username) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),0(root),27(sudo),1001(developers)
```

and groups

```
www-data sudo developers
```

So it seems that the user is inside the sudo group, however it doesn't have access to the iptables command, i.e. if I type as "username" iptalbes it tells me command not found.

Furthermore, I was reading about the /etc/sudoers that you can give access to specific users. I've changed from 440 to 740 the permission rights and I uncommented

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Now everytime I type sudo whatever command I get

```
username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Some help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: A group is normally defined with a % prefix in the sudoers file and so sudo should be %sudo

Comment: Thanks Raman but how do I fix both the iptables issue and the fact that I cannot type sudo command anymore?

Comment: By running visudo and prefixing sudo with %sudo?

Comment: Currently I can't change anything...it always gives me : username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Can you not login as root and do it?

Comment: I hadnt activate root user...It seems that it's messed up now...not sure what to do

Comment: You will need to log on via a recovery media and then either change the /etc/sudoers file manually after mounting the disk or chroot to your mounted disk and set up a root password.